# Rails 4: Multiple image upload using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nested-forms, image-uploading

I'm looking to upload multiple images to my 'locations' model. I've called the images model 'assets'. One location has multiple assets. I'm also using paperclip to handle the uploads and nested_form to allow selecting multiple assets.

Weirdly, the locations hash looks to be passing the variables correctly, but they don't appear to be being picked up by the assets model. Any help would be great!

*Location model*

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :location_post
  has_many :posts, :through => :location_post  
  has_many :assets, dependent: :destroy

  attr_accessor :asset, :assets_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true 
end
```

*Asset model*

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :location

   has_attached_file :asset,
                    :styles => {
                      :blurred => "600x300^",:large => "600x600>", :medium => "250x250^" , :thumb => "100x100^"},
                      #:source_file_options =>  {:all => '-rotate "-90>"'},
                      :convert_options => {
                      :all => '-auto-orient', :blurred => "-blur 0x6 +repage -resize 600x300^" 
                        },
                      :storage => :s3,
                      :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                      :bucket => "[bucketname]",
                      :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"    

validates_attachment_content_type :asset, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

end
```

*Locations Controller*

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

...

  def new
    @location = Location.new
    @location.assets.build
    @georesult = Geocoder.search(params[:query])
  end

  def create

    @location = Location.find_or_create_by(name: location_params[:name])


    respond_to do |format|
     if @location.save
       format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: ' <borat voice> Great success! </borat voice>' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @location }
     else
       format.html { render :new }
       format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /locations/1
  # PATCH/PUT /locations/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
     if @location.update(location_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully updated.'  }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @location }
     else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
  end

 ...

 private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
 def location_params
      params[:location].permit(:name, :notes, :longitude, :country, :latitude, :query, assets_attributes: [ :asset, :asset_content_type, :asset_file_name, :tempfile, :asset_file_size, :asset_updated_at, :_destroy])
    end
 end
```

*Form View*

```
<%= nested_form_for(@location, :html=> {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>

...

  <%= f.fields_for :assets do |a| %>
    <%= a.file_field :asset %>
    <%= a.link_to_remove "Remove this image" %>
  <% end %>
<%= f.link_to_add "Add an image", :assets %>

...

    <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => "btn btn-success submit_location" %>

<% end %>
```

*Log output*

```
Processing by LocationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"n4spoLjq4B3sZSJjqsGFRVjkseOwGgvquAHATBRG1Nk=", "location"=>{"name"=>"York", "notes"=>"", "lat
itude"=>"53.96230079999999", "longitude"=>"-1.0818844", "country"=>"", "assets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"asset"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile
:0x007ff739b7bb68 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/sc/gps8hkgj7yg31j81gpnfg9h00000gn/T/RackMultipart20140706-43312-kdpghs>, @original_filename=
"78509.max1024.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"location[assets_attributes][0][asset]\"; filen
ame=\"78509.max1024.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"240"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Location Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations"  WHERE "locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 240]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/locations/240
Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

Comment: Try changing `location_params` to `params.require(:location).permit(:name, :notes, :longitude, :country, :latitude, :query, assets_attributes: [ :asset, :asset_content_type, :asset_file_name, :tempfile, :asset_file_size, :asset_updated_at, :_destroy])`

Comment: Is your action complete? I don't think you're passing the params or calling save on the created objects.

Comment: @Pavan Thanks but tried this and no dice. The logs show the hash is being built correctly as well, but just not responding right. Any other ideas?

Comment: @mus I believe it to be a complete action. Surely it wouldn't be in the log if it wasn't being passed? In terms of the 'create' function, i'm just running it as normal. I will amended the above post to include this.

Comment: Can you show us your `create` action?

Comment: @Pavan I've now added it above.

Comment: Why do you you have this line `@location = Location.find_or_create_by(name: location_params[:name])`? It is supposed to be `@location = Location.new(location_params)`

Comment: And the `location_params` as i suggested.

Comment: @Pavan Aha... it's for a separate bit of logic to ensure Locations are unique. I wonder if this is what's causing the issue. May be a separate post to ask how to pass extra variables through a find_or_create function.

Comment: Did it worked if you changed it like i said?

Comment: Hmm, no. Same response. That suggests to me that it's not the  `@location = Location.new(location_params)`. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you tried my both suggestions? i mean `location_params` and that line?

Comment: @Pavan Yes, to no avail. No change. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see couple of problems in your code:

First thing, you need to remove the following line from `Location` model:

```
attr_accessor :asset, :assets_attributes
```

as its making `asset` and `asset_attributes` as virtual attributes which is why they are not saved in database. Also, you don't need `asset` attribute in `Location` model as its been taken care by `Asset` model.

Then, update the `location_params` as suggested by @Pavan:

```
def location_params
  ## Use `require` method
  params.require(:location).permit(:name, :notes, :longitude, :country, :latitude, :query, assets_attributes: [ :asset, :asset_content_type, :asset_file_name, :tempfile, :asset_file_size, :asset_updated_at, :_destroy])
end
```

Next, update the `create` action as below to ensure Locations are unique by name:

```
def create
  @location = Location.find_by(name: location_params[:name])
  unless @location
    @location = Location.new(location_params)
  end 
  respond_to do |format|
    if @location.save
      format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: ' <borat voice> Great success! </borat voice>' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @location }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `<%= a.file_field :asset, :multiple=>"true",:name=>"location[assets][asset][]"%>` for handling multiple uploads.

Hope it helps